# Оптимизация кода C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, асимптотика

Очень многие тестирующие системы устанавливают максимальное время работы кода, моя история как раз об этом. Код не проходит на последнем тесте из-за превышения времени работы (дольше 1 сек). Задача такая:
Вход : массив из чисел
Вывод: массив, где каждый i,j элемент - это сумма всех элементов до ij-го введенного массива.
Пример:

```
Вход
2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Выход

```
1 3 6
5 12 21
```

Мой кусочек кода:

```
    for (long int i = 0; i < array.rows; i++) {
        for (long int j = 0; j < array.cols; j++) {
            cin >> input;
            array.data[i][j] = input;
            long int k = 0;
            for (long int t = 0; t <= i; t++) {
                for (long int l = 0; l <= j; l++) {
                    k += array.data[t][l];
                }
            }
            cout << k << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Есть ли идеи, как ускорить?

Comment: Лучше, когда такие вопросы включают 1. абсолютно точную исходную постановку задачи со всеми деталями, 2. URL проверяющей системы. Очевидно, что если в таких системах не проходит по времени - надо не байты передвигать, а менять сам алгоритм.

Comment: Правильное решение должно работать за O(n\*\*2), а приведённое в вопросе работает за O(n\*\*4).

Answer (score 6):

Проблема в том, что ваше решение пересчитывает каждый раз заново всю сумму элементов, что приводит к ужасной асимптотике в `О(n^4)`. Эту задачу можно решить с помощью [динамического программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Для этого подумайте, как можно получить ответ для i,j за `O(1)` из уже имеющихся данных, а не за `О(n^2)` циклами.

Небольшая подсказка: пусть `d` - искомый массив. Как узнать `d[i][j]` зная значения `a[i][j]`, `d[i-1][j-1]`, `d[i-1][j]` и `d[i][j-1]`?

Это решение также позволяет помимо оптимизации времени работы до `О(n^2)` оптимизировать память до `O(n)` если заметить, что мы всегда работаем только с двумя строками массива `d`: текущей и предыдущей.

Answer (score 5):

Код переведён с Питона [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653555/find-the-nxn-submatrix-with-the-highest-number-of-1s/62654932#62654932), работает за n^2 (количество элементов в матрице).

Исходные данные в `a[][]`, кумулятивные суммы в `cs[][]` такой же размерности. Если новый массив не требуется, а исходные данные сохранять не нужно, то вычисления можно производить внутри того же `a[][]`.

Копируется первая строка, затем делается один проход с вычислением сумм по столбцам, затем проход с вычислением по строкам.

```
for (int c = 0; c < a.cols; c++)
    cs[0][c] = a[0][c];

for (int r = 1; r < a.rows; r++)
    for (int c = 0; c < a.cols; c++)
        cs[r][c] = cs[r-1][c] + a[r][c];

 for (int r = 0; r < a.rows; r++)
     for (int c = 1; c < a.cols; c++)
         cs[r][c] += cs[r][c-1];
```

Comment: я бы добавил в ответ пару строчек пояснений. О том, что cs - это массив промежуточных сумм, которые высчитываются одна из другой... Но Ваш ответ всё равно прекрасен!